# pivot_longer by match in other column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset similar to the following that I've wrangling from two different datasets using tidyverse:
[image]

What I want is to pivot_longer resident_census_total and visitor_census_total into a new column called 'census_totals'. However, I also need them to match the appropriate status, e.g. when status == 'Resident', I need the 'census_totals' column to have the value from resident_census_total, and vice versa with Visitor. This is where I'm running into trouble, because just using

```
pivot_longer(
  cols = c("resident_census_total, "visitor_census_total"),
  names_to = "census_totals"
)
```

leads to the data from the two columns simply alternating, rather than matching appropriately.

Dummy dataframe below:

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  location = rep(c("j210", "s34", "q3"), 6),
  day = rep(c("Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"), each = 3),
  period = rep(c("2019_fire", "2020_YOY", "2021_YOY"), 6),
  total_agents = c(3585, 1234, 0, 456, 124, 688, 24, 1235, 77, 4578, 357, 124, 
                   2345, 14, 1223, 345, 123, 22),
  Status = rep(c("Resident", "Visitor"), 9),
  resident_census_total = rep(c(127, 345, 1123), 6),
  visitor_census_total = rep(c(0, 266, 456), 6)
) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd great if you could provide an example of your desired output so that our answers would be more accurate.

Based on your question, I'm guessing you want a column of `consensus_totals` to replace `resident_census_total` and `visitor_census_total`. You don't really need to use `pivot_longer` in this case, just use `case_when()` to match your `Status` and output the appropriate columns.

### Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

You can use `ifelse(Status == "Resident", resident_census_total, visitor_census_total)` to replace `case_when()` if you're sure you only have TWO `Status`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dummy %>% mutate(census_totals = case_when(Status == "Resident" ~ resident_census_total,
                                           Status == "Visitor" ~ visitor_census_total)) %>% 
  select(-resident_census_total, -visitor_census_total)
```

### Output

```
   location   day    period total_agents   Status census_totals
1      j210 Day 1 2019_fire         3585 Resident           127
2       s34 Day 1  2020_YOY         1234  Visitor           266
3        q3 Day 1  2021_YOY            0 Resident          1123
4      j210 Day 2 2019_fire          456  Visitor             0
5       s34 Day 2  2020_YOY          124 Resident           345
6        q3 Day 2  2021_YOY          688  Visitor           456
7      j210 Day 3 2019_fire           24 Resident           127
8       s34 Day 3  2020_YOY         1235  Visitor           266
9        q3 Day 3  2021_YOY           77 Resident          1123
10     j210 Day 1 2019_fire         4578  Visitor             0
11      s34 Day 1  2020_YOY          357 Resident           345
12       q3 Day 1  2021_YOY          124  Visitor           456
13     j210 Day 2 2019_fire         2345 Resident           127
14      s34 Day 2  2020_YOY           14  Visitor           266
15       q3 Day 2  2021_YOY         1223 Resident          1123
16     j210 Day 3 2019_fire          345  Visitor             0
17      s34 Day 3  2020_YOY          123 Resident           345
18       q3 Day 3  2021_YOY           22  Visitor           456
```

### Your dataset for reference

```
  location   day    period total_agents   Status resident_census_total visitor_census_total
1      j210 Day 1 2019_fire         3585 Resident                   127                    0
2       s34 Day 1  2020_YOY         1234  Visitor                   345                  266
3        q3 Day 1  2021_YOY            0 Resident                  1123                  456
4      j210 Day 2 2019_fire          456  Visitor                   127                    0
5       s34 Day 2  2020_YOY          124 Resident                   345                  266
6        q3 Day 2  2021_YOY          688  Visitor                  1123                  456
7      j210 Day 3 2019_fire           24 Resident                   127                    0
8       s34 Day 3  2020_YOY         1235  Visitor                   345                  266
9        q3 Day 3  2021_YOY           77 Resident                  1123                  456
10     j210 Day 1 2019_fire         4578  Visitor                   127                    0
11      s34 Day 1  2020_YOY          357 Resident                   345                  266
12       q3 Day 1  2021_YOY          124  Visitor                  1123                  456
13     j210 Day 2 2019_fire         2345 Resident                   127                    0
14      s34 Day 2  2020_YOY           14  Visitor                   345                  266
15       q3 Day 2  2021_YOY         1223 Resident                  1123                  456
16     j210 Day 3 2019_fire          345  Visitor                   127                    0
17      s34 Day 3  2020_YOY          123 Resident                   345                  266
18       q3 Day 3  2021_YOY           22  Visitor                  1123                  456
```